# Why would spell circles written in blood which contain iron be more powerful than using gold or silver ink?

Tags: magic, metals, blood

Set in the 13th century A. D. the search for Philosopher's stone which is said to allow user to transmute base metal into gold or perhaps even diamonds as some have claimed. Since then people starts to conduct experiments using spell circles written in ink made out of a wide range of materials, precious metal such as gold and silver produces a much better results however they noticed that blood which contains iron has the best performance of all materials. They discovered that iron filing or iron powder in it's purest form didn't even come close to blood in particular human blood, they even claimed that blood must be one of the ingredients to create the Philosopher's stone. Only warm blood with high iron content used in spell circle can create the most powerful magic compared to using other precious metal and why is that?

Comment: This question is fairly broad, and hinges completely on how your magic works. Technologically speaking blood will hardly ever have an advantage over pure(r) metals for conductivity.

Comment: Because blood carries the life force, obviously.

Comment: @Plutian except if the "power" doesn't come from iron itself but from the blood part. Or even the compound of blood + iron. It might even be entirely divorced of physical properties of each but refer to the metaphysical ones. Especially if intertwined - symbolically blood=life and iron=tools (or progres, industry, building block for these, etc). I agree, it's too broad. There are many possible explanations and they'd all be an exercise in creative writing more than actually grounded to the question.

Answer (score 1):

If the question definitely has to do with elements and not life force, then perhaps it is because they aren't aware of the mixture.  It's easy to determine that blood has iron (actually, I have no idea how a medieval society would determine that, but let's say they have), but what they might not be able to tell is that blood also has zinc, copper, cobalt, and nickel.  The magical field effectiveness could come from the combination of these.

Especially also if the mixture involves oxygenation. When using iron by itself they might, being alchemists who are obsessed with purity, be using the best iron.  But rusty iron would be closer to what we have in blood, hence the redness.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if different metals taste differently, but tasting blood might be a way to determine its metallic content.

Comment: Not gonna lie, now I want to do a metal taste test.  I mean, we know blood tastes like pennies when you get punched in the face, so you can definitely taste copper.  But I wonder what cobalt and nickel taste like.